# How to add SMS in inbox and sent messages in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, sdk, sms

I'm trying to write an app that has to manipulate my inbox and my sent messages without sending or receiving a message.

This [tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) shows me how I can send messages, but I want my phone to think that I sent one, without actually sending one.

I've searched in the Android References and I think I need to use:

- SMS Manager
- SMS Message

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `ContentProvider` with URL "content://sms/inbox" and "content://sms/sent" and do an `insert` there.

Comment: It works this way,but there has to be another way to do this. 
Also read this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to write an app that has to manipulate my inbox and my sent messages without sending or receivin
>   a message.

Android, the OS, does not have an "inbox" or "sent messages".

Some SMS applications do. However, I am aware of none that offer documented and supported APIs for you to "manipulate" them this way.

Comment: But there is a standard Messaging app in Android isn't it? So if i could manipulate that one ...

Comment: @Ruben: "But there is a standard Messaging app in Android isn't it?" -- not really. It is replaced on some devices by others. "So if i could manipulate that one" -- it does not offer documented and supported APIs for you to "manipulate" it this way.

Comment: **thanks** for the infos and for the link, not going to do it now ;)